# can not click a button using ui4j

Tags: ui4j

i have this part of a website

```
<tr class="rgPager GridPager">
            <td colspan="6"><table border="0" style="width:100%;border-spacing:0;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="rgStatus"><div id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_statusPanel" style="visibility:hidden;">
                        &nbsp;
                    </div></td><td class="rgPagerCell NextPrevNumericAndAdvanced"><div class="rgWrap rgArrPart1">
                        <input type="submit" name="dnn$ctr521$View$episkopisiGrid$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl02" value=" " onclick="return false;" title="First Page" class="rgPageFirst" /> <input type="submit" name="dnn$ctr521$View$episkopisiGrid$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl03" value=" " onclick="return false;" title="Previous Page" class="rgPagePrev" />
                    </div><div class="rgWrap rgNumPart">
                        <a onclick="return false;" class="rgCurrentPage" href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr521$View$episkopisiGrid$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl05','')"><span>1</span></a><a href="javascript:__doPostBack('dnn$ctr521$View$episkopisiGrid$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl07','')"><span>2</span></a>
                    </div><div class="rgWrap rgArrPart2">
                        <input type="submit" name="dnn$ctr521$View$episkopisiGrid$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl10" value=" " title="Next Page" class="rgPageNext" /> <input type="submit" name="dnn$ctr521$View$episkopisiGrid$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl11" value=" " title="Last Page" class="rgPageLast" />
                    </div><div class="rgWrap rgInfoPart">
                          Εγγραφές <strong>1</strong> - <strong>50</strong> / <strong>60</strong>.
                    </div><div class="rgWrap rgAdvPart">
                        <span id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_GoToPageLabel" class="rgPagerLabel">Page:</span><span id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_GoToPageTextBox_wrapper" class="RadInput RadInput_Default" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="text" value="1" id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_GoToPageTextBox_text" name="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_GoToPageTextBox_text" class="riTextBox riEnabled rgPagerTextBox" style="width:10px;" /><input style="visibility:hidden;margin:-18px 0 0 -1px;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;border:0;padding:0;" id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_GoToPageTextBox" class="rdfd_" value="1" type="text" title="" /><input style="visibility:hidden;margin:-18px 0 0 -1px;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;border:0;padding:0;" id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_GoToPageTextBox_Value" class="rdfd_" name="dnn$ctr521$View$episkopisiGrid$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$GoToPageTextBox" value="1" type="text" title="" /><input id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_GoToPageTextBox_ClientState" name="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_GoToPageTextBox_ClientState" type="hidden" /></span><span id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_PageOfLabel" class="rgPagerLabel">of 2</span>&nbsp;<input type="submit" name="dnn$ctr521$View$episkopisiGrid$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$GoToPageLinkButton" value="Go" onclick="var gtpi = $get('dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_GoToPageTextBox'); if(gtpi.value == 1 || gtpi.value == '')return false;" id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_GoToPageLinkButton" class="rgPagerButton" /><span id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_ChangePageSizeLabel" class="rgPagerLabel">Εγγραφές</span><span id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_ChangePageSizeTextBox_wrapper" class="RadInput RadInput_Default" style="white-space:nowrap;"><input type="text" value="50" id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_ChangePageSizeTextBox_text" name="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_ChangePageSizeTextBox_text" class="riTextBox riEnabled rgPagerTextBox" style="width:20px;" /><input style="visibility:hidden;margin:-18px 0 0 -1px;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;border:0;padding:0;" id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_ChangePageSizeTextBox" class="rdfd_" value="50" type="text" title="" /><input style="visibility:hidden;margin:-18px 0 0 -1px;width:1px;height:1px;overflow:hidden;border:0;padding:0;" id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_ChangePageSizeTextBox_Value" class="rdfd_" name="dnn$ctr521$View$episkopisiGrid$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ChangePageSizeTextBox" value="50" type="text" title="" /><input id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_ChangePageSizeTextBox_ClientState" name="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_ChangePageSizeTextBox_ClientState" type="hidden" /></span><input type="submit" name="dnn$ctr521$View$episkopisiGrid$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ChangePageSizeLinkButton" value="Change" onclick="var cpsi = document.getElementById(&quot;dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_ChangePageSizeTextBox&quot;); if ( cpsi.value > 60 || cpsi.value == 50){cpsi.value=Math.min(60,50);return false;};" id="dnn_ctr521_View_episkopisiGrid_ctl00_ctl03_ctl01_ChangePageSizeLinkButton" class="rgPagerButton" />
                    </div></td>
                </tr>
            </table></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
```

containing a button

```
<input type="submit"    
name="dnn$ctr521$View$episkopisiGrid$ctl00$ctl03$ctl01$ctl10"   
value=" " title="Next Page" class="rgPageNext" />
```

for some reason i just cant get it to click on it.
I tried this

```
subworks.query("tfoot").queryAll("div").get(3).query("input").click();
```

Which is the correct element, since i am getting the correct value (next page) when i call `.getValue()`

It seems that the page doesnt change after i run this command. I use `.getBody()` but i am getting the same html as before the click command.

Any help?